# Performantly create a list of python dictionaries by combining a numpy array and a list of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find a time and memory performant way to create a dictionary, by combining both a list of tuples and an 1d numpy array. Hereby, each dictionary should have the following structure:

```
{"id": <first elem from tuple>, "name": <second elem from tuple>, "text": <third elem from tuple>, "value": <elem from array>}
```

The list of tuples looks as follows:

```
list_of_tuples = [("id1", "name1", "text1"), ("id2", "name2", "text2")]
```

Also, the numpy array has the same amount of elements as the list and contains elements of type np.float16:

```
value_array = np.ndarray([0.42, np.nan])
```

Also, all NaN-values are to be filtered out. The result of above example should be:

```
{"id": "id1", "name": "name1", "text": "text1", "value": 0.42}
```

I did get it to work like this:

```
[
    dict(
        dict(zip(["id", "name", "text"], list_of_tuples[index])),
        **{"value": value},
    )
    for index, value in enumerate(value_array)
    if not (math.isnan(value))
]
```

However, this is horribly slow for many entries and using the index to get entries from the list feels wrong/ inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely work without having to use the index explicitly. This should provide an improvement in performance.

```
value_array_indices = np.argwhere(~np.isnan(value_array)) 
list_of_tuples = np.array(list_of_tuples)[value_array_indices[0]]
value_array = value_array[value_array_indices[0]]
[{"id": x[0], "name": x[1], "text": x[2], "value": v} for x,v in zip(list_of_tuples, value_array)]
```

Comment: grand, thank you! value_array_indices in your code gave me an array of 1-element arrays. accessing them with [0] then only gave me one element. that was easily fixed using: np.concatenate(np.argwhere(~np.isnan(value_array)), axis=0)

Comment: You forgot to filter out of the NaNs, but it is easily fixed by putting an `if not math.isnan(v)` clause in your list comprehension.

Comment: @alaniwi: `value_array_indices` only captures the indices of non-nan values.

Comment: @pecey Sorry yes, I see what you've done now - I didn't read it properly.

Comment: Since the last line involves iteration, I expect it would be faster if the `zip` arguments were lists.  I also suspect that the `if not math.isnan(v)` clause would be faster than the `argwhere` approach.  That may though depend on the proportion of `nan`.  Since `dict` have to be created individually, `numpy` doesn't buy much, if anything.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, I am not sure I understand why `if not math.isnan(v)` would be faster? Is it because you would be iterating the entire thing just once? As opposed to this way, where once I am separating out nans and then iterating over the smaller lists? Also, I am not sure why zip would work faster with lists.

Answer (score 1):

*Looks like someone posted a similar solution while I was writing this, but I'll post it anyway because of the timings measured, and some words of explanation.*

Using the code suggested below, and with test inputs of length a million (which include a single NaN), I am seeing it go down to under 30% of the time compared to the code in the question.

```
Time: 0.3486933708190918
{'id': 'id0', 'name': 'name0', 'text': 'text0', 'value': 0.0} {'id': 'id999999', 'name': 'name999999', 'text': 'text999999', 'value': 999999.0} 999999
Time: 1.2175893783569336
{'id': 'id0', 'name': 'name0', 'text': 'text0', 'value': 0.0} {'id': 'id999999', 'name': 'name999999', 'text': 'text999999', 'value': 999999.0} 999999
```

I think the difference here is *partly* not having to index the list of tuples, but also I suspect that a large part of it is not having to instantiate a `zip` object for every element.  You are dealing with a small number of dictionary keys with the same names each time, so you really do not need the flexibility that `zip` affords here, and it is more straightforward just to create the dictionary from a simple explicit expression.

(The `zip(list_of_tuples, value_array)` is obviously only creating one `zip` object for the whole operation, so is not significant.)

I've also suggested `from math import isnan` here rather than doing an attribute lookup to get `math.isnan` every time, although the difference turns out to be relatively unimportant.

```
from math import isnan
import numpy as np
import time

# construct some test data
n = 1000000
value_array = np.arange(n, dtype=np.float)
value_array[n // 2] = np.nan
list_of_tuples = [(f"id{i}", f"name{i}", f"text{i}")
                  for i in range(len(value_array))]

# timings for suggested alternative method
t0 = time.time()
l = [{"id": t[0],
      "name": t[1],
      "text": t[2],
      "value": v}
     for t, v in zip(list_of_tuples, value_array) if not isnan(v)]
t1 = time.time()
print("Time:", t1 - t0)
print(l[0], l[-1], len(l))

# timings for the method in the question
t0 = time.time()
l = \
[
    dict(
        dict(zip(["id", "name", "text"], list_of_tuples[index])),
        **{"value": value},
    )
    for index, value in enumerate(value_array)
    if not (isnan(value))
]
t1 = time.time()
print("Time:", t1 - t0)
print(l[0], l[-1], len(l))
```

Also tried and rejected: create a boolean array of `not isnan` values, using

```
not_isnan_array = np.logical_not(np.isnan(value_array))
```

and then in the list comprehension you can do:

```
... for t, v, not_isnan in zip(list_of_tuples, value_array, not_isnan_array) if not_isnan
```

but it has almost no effect on the timing so does not justify the extra memory usage.

### UPDATE

Further experimentation with hybrid versions (between the original in the question and the proposed alternative) shows that, as I suspected, most of the difference comes from the avoidance of creating a `zip` object on every iteration.  The avoidance of explicitly indexing the list of tuples accounts for only a small part of the speedup.